# "volume doesn’t implement mount" for `gio mount`

Tags: google-drive

In Ubuntu 22.04, when I do `gio mount google-drive://<my email>` I get "volume doesn’t implement mount".
I used the Online Accounts Settings dialog to log into my account, I have gvfs, gvfs-fuse, gfvs-backends and ran the daemon, I tried to use dbus-run-session.

In my other laptop, a 20.04, the mount works fine. Not sure where the difference lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this is because my terminal is a Flatpak package and Flatpak sets `GIO_USE_VFS=local` which is passed to the terminal and to my shell. Unsetting the value in my `.zshrc` fixed the issue.